# Cant see objects in unity when playing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can see the objects when I modify the scene but I can't when I play the game. They have colliders and I can "feel" them but not see them. They are simply invisible.

I tried to change the mesh type of the tile and check the visibility. I hoped one of these procedures will help the situation and make the objects visible. Actually, nothing changed.

Comment: Show us the Inspector properties on the objects. We can't help you "telepathically" :)

Comment: Can you please provide some screenshots of your editor scene view and some of your game view?

Comment: i am smart and i solved it by myself. I cant just take "empty" object and give it a texture. I need to take a visible object like square or circle or triangle or tithed and give it another texture.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your Main Camera's culling masks do not include those of the objects that you can't see. Go to the inspector of your main camera, and make sure the "culling mask" is set to "everything".